# How to check the execution status of codepipeline in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-codepipeline

I am working on a codepippeline for a lambda.
Here the approach is to run a codepipiline with 2 stages: source and build.
Once the build is successfull: a s3 bucket is connected to it and that bucket will have a zip file for a lambda to execute; this zip file gets updated everytime there is any change done to it and the codepipeline gets executed for the same change.
So basically the codepipeline should run successfully and update the s3 bucket file.

while trying to do this in Terraform; the problem am facing is that the codepipeline module once gets triggered then at the same time my lambda module also gets triggered assuming that the codepipeline is executed and starts searching for the zip file in the specific bucket. But as the pipeline is not executed completely and the zip file is not updated ; my lambda module throws an error saying there is no file availbale.
I have tried with using depends_on, time_sleep, but it didnt work. can anyone plz help me to fix this issue.
the issue is to get the confirmation that codepipeline module is successfully executed and then the lambda module should get started.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question and take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a single Terraform deployment that creates a pipeline for building the Lambda zip, that also deploys the Lambda zip file. Those need to be two separate Terraform deployments. Or more ideally, just have Terraform create the CodePipeline, and add a deploy stage to the pipeline that deploys the Lambda function.